# Bootstrap <select> width, content too wide when resizing window

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can i make the dropdown the size to fit the content (in my case it happens when shrinking the browser to less than some certain size, then content start to dissapear? I preferably do not want any custom css, anything built in to bootstrap to support this?

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="inputForm" name="inputForm" novalidate>
<div class="well">
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-3 control-label"><strong>4.</strong>&nbsp;Select thing</label>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <select class="form-control">
            <option>Short
            </option>
            <option>Medium lenght
            </option>
            <option>Much much much longer text not fitting when resizing
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: You are using a native select box, did you try a bootstrap dropdown? http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**Option 1:** You can add `width:auto` to the select, although then it will always size to fit the longest content, and ignore your `col` class. See the snippet:

```html
 <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="inputForm" name="inputForm" novalidate>
<div class="well">
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-3 control-label"><strong>4.</strong>&nbsp;Select thing</label>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <select class="form-control" style="width:auto;">
            <option>Short
            </option>
            <option>Medium lenght
            </option>
            <option>Much much much longer text not fitting when resizing
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

**Option 2** would be to use an inline form, see [**this bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/xgOyCwbEuC) for a functioning example

Comment: Thanks, maybe a solution, but don't feel nice to put css in the html directly

Comment: I would tend to agree with you completely on that. Your other option would be to use an [inline form](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline), which sets all widths to auto, but you lose the control the `.col...` classes give you.

Comment: @Vixen, I added a link to a bootply with the inline form option

Answer (score 28):

Old question, new answer. You can set the class to `w-auto` in bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 8):

### **New answer**

*Bootstrap v5*

You can put your select element in a container :

```html
<div class="container w-25">
  <select class="form-select  h-100 w-100" aria-label="">
    <option>Images</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using bootstrap's [dropdown widget](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns) which will allow wrapping http://jsfiddle.net/g4s59a9a/:

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button id="dLabel" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown trigger
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
    
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
    <li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
      <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">
      Much much much longer text not fitting when resizing
      </a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
      <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">
        Smaller text
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Does not seem like the selection shows once you have selected it.

Comment: You'd have to do this with JS - fiddle updated with an example: http://jsfiddle.net/g4s59a9a/1/